# Showing DTPicker Calender Year drop down Visual Basic

Tags: vb6

I used DTPicker control for selecting the date in my application. When i click on the picker control its drop down the calender and if I click the year in top near with month it shows the up down button for selecting the year.

My question is, is there any chance we can show the up down year selection button by default without clicking the year. check the attached image and give me some ideas. Thanks
 [image]

Comment: There is no image attached? Not even an URL to an image...

Comment: Try to show us a little bit more, it may help

Comment: Not if you're talking about the standard DTPicker control.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your image all I can say that to get different functionality of user controls in VB6 you either have to buy one you like or create your own. The standard MS controls generally provide all the functionality required and also have the benefit of being both familiar to users and meeting MS guidelines.